# multi-part identifier could not be bound on insert from another database on another server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert information from one database on one server into a table on another with out inserting a duplicate and i get the title error. here is the code

```
INSERT INTO [Datamaxx].[dbo].[data_job_t] (JobCode, Description) 
SELECT job_no, description
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',
'Data Source=server\server;Integrated Security=SSPI')
.cas_tekworks.dbo.jobs WHERE Job_Status ='A' and data_job_t.JobCode  not in (select Jobcode from [Datamaxx].[dbo].[data_job_t])
```

Comment: This surely isn't MySQL, looks more like SQL Server. Which one is it exactly?

Comment: sql server - sorry about that

Comment: I figured it out. the solution is .... and job_no not in (select Jobcode from [Datamaxx].[dbo].[data_job_t])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this....

**job_no not in** instead of data_job_t.JobCode

```
INSERT INTO [Datamaxx].[dbo].[data_job_t] (JobCode, Description) 
SELECT job_no, description
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',
'Data Source=server\server;Integrated Security=SSPI')
.cas_tekworks.dbo.jobs WHERE Job_Status ='A' and job_no not in (select Jobcode from [Datamaxx].[dbo].[data_job_t])
```